# Reading stream line by line without knowing its encoding

Tags: node.js, stream

I have a situation where I need to process some data from a stream line by line. The problem is that the encoding of the data is not known in advance; it might be `UTF-8` or any legacy single-byte encoding (e.g. `Latin1`, `ISO-8859-5`, etc). It will *not* be `UTF16` or exotics like `EBCDIC`, so I can reasonably expect `\n` to be unambiguous, so in theory I can split it into lines. At some point, when I encounter an empty line, I will need to feed the rest of the stream somewhere else (without splitting it into lines, but still without any reencoding); think in terms of HTTP-style headers followed by an opaque body.

Here is what I got:

```
function processStream(stream) {
    var buffer = '';

    function splitLines(data) {
        buffer += data;
        var lf = buffer.indexOf('\n');
        while (lf >= 0) {
            var line = buffer.substr(0, lf - 1);
            buffer = buffer.substr(lf + 1);
            this.emit('line', line);
            lf = buffer.indexOf('\n');
        }
    }

    function processHeader(line) {
        if (line.length) {
            // do something with the line
        } else {
            // end of headers, stop splitting lines and start processing the body
            this
            .removeListener('data', splitLines)
            .removeAllListeners('line')
            .on('data', processBody);
            if (buffer.length) {
                // process leftover buffer as part of the body
                processBody(buffer);
                buffer = '';
            }
        }
    }

    function processBody(data) {
        // do something with the body chunks
    }

    stream.setEncoding('binary');
    stream
    .on('data', splitLines)
    .on('line', processHeader);
}
```

It does the job, but the problem is that the `binary` encoding is deprecated and will probably disappear in the future, leaving me without that option. All other `Buffer` encodings will either mangle the data or fail to decode it altogether if (most likely, when) it does not match the encoding. Working with `Uint8Array` instead will mean slow and inconvenient Javascript loops over the data just to find a newline.

Any suggestions on how to split a stream into lines on the fly, while remaining encoding-agnostic *without* using `binary` encoding?

Comment: Why don't you use 'hex' data instead of binary? You say all other encodings mangle the data, but anything represented in binary should be able to be represented in hex. Granted you might get up to 7 bits of padding if your data is not represented in octets.

Comment: Because that will effectively use double the amount of memory for each data chunk, it will require unnecessary conversions to and from hex just for the sake of splitting lines, and also searching for a `0A` substring will need an additional check if it falls on an even offset into the string and might need a second search if it doesn't. Overall, it seems neither clean nor effective. We're talking about actual textual data here, it is not binary; it is just that I'm handling it in `binary` encoding for the sake of not doing any I/O conversion on it.

Comment: (and yes, I know that `binary` actually involves conversion, but it preserves the data in a representation that can be reversed into the original bytes)

Comment: I already gave you my arguments against hex, I'm just clarifying that I'm not handling actual binary data.

Comment: I'm not trying to argue with you. But your last statement was confusing (by last I mean "it preserves the data in a representation that can be reversed into the original bytes"). I know that splitting in hex is more cumbersome than in binary, but the only difference between them otherwise is the number of characters representing a byte, so backwards forwards conversion is essentially the same. To split it you need to read it -> byte by byte will require a loop, other solutions will require conversion. I see no way around it.

Comment: There is no benefit in iterating over a `hex` string byte by byte, compared to iterating over an actual `Buffer` byte by byte. It likely has the same efficiency iteration-wise, while having a bigger overhead when comparing the actual byte values (comparing 2-character strings vs comparing primitive integers).

Comment: Streams with the binary encoding are some kinda of a hack (that's why they will be removed), because they represent a byte to char conversion without specifying any encoding. So, in your case, you don't want to use any encoding, do the work with the Buffer class only and finish by a Buffer.toString conversion (and you *will* have to make an encoding choice then) for each discovered line.

Comment: `Buffer` gives a very rudimentary set of tools to work with, and I was reluctant to reimplement in JS all methods that I need, but it turned out `Buffer`-specific pure JS reimplementations of some `String` methods are even _faster_ than native V8 string methods, so that might very well turn out to be the best approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not a Javascript developer.

> At some point, when I encounter an empty line, I will need to feed the rest of the stream somewhere else (without splitting it into lines, but still without any reencoding)

Right. In that case, it sounds like you *really* don't want to think about the data as text at all. Treat it as you would any binary data, and split it on byte 0x0A. (Note that if it came from Windows to start with, you *might* want to also remove any trailing 0x0D value.)

I know it's text really, but without any encoding information, it's dangerous to impose any sort of interpretation on the data.

So you should keep two pieces of state:

- A list of byte arrays
- The current buffer

When you receive data, you logically want to create a new array with the current buffer prepending the new data. (For efficiency you may not want to actually create such an array, but I would do so to start with, until you've got it working.) Look for any 0x0A bytes, and split the array accordingly (create a new byte array as a "slice" of the existing array, and add the slice to the list). The new "current buffer" will be whatever data you have left after the final 0x0A.

If you see two 0x0A values in a row, then you'd go into your second mode of just copying the data.

This is all assuming that the Javascript / Node combination allows you to manipulate binary data *as* binary data, but I'd be shocked if it didn't. The important point is *not* to interpret it as text at any point.

Comment: Did you mean to say **if it came from Windows to start with, you _might_ want to also remove any trailing 0x0D value**?

Comment: Actually, what you describe is basically what I'm doing already, but using a hackish conversion to a "binary" Unicode string (i.e. one where every Unicode character is constrained to the 0..255 range and representing a single input byte). I was under the impression that reimplementing basic `String` functionality in pure JS would incur a severe performance hit, but to my surprise, a pure JS implementation of `String.indexOf` working on a binary `Buffer` turned out to be _faster_ than the native V8 implementation working on actual strings. This seems to be the most promising approach so far.

Comment: @lanzz: Given that it never has to do any encoding, I'm not surprised - and of course you don't need to implement a general-purpose, multi-length `indexOf`... you're just trying to find a single byte. More importantly, your code reflects reality accurately: you don't really have text; you just have binary data which you can't sensibly interpret other than the *tiny* bit of information about what would represent a line break in the right encoding.